# How to convert a list of numbers to a list of strings?

Tags: python, list, numbers, quotes

I'm knocking my head against a wall regarding adding quotes to a list of numbers.

How do I add **single quotes** to this list of numbers?

```py
num = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to convert the individual elements to strings.  Note that the strings do *not* contain quotes.  They are simply delimited by quotes when displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```py
num = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_list = [str(i) for i in num]

#output
print(new_list)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
num= list(map(str, num))
print(num)
#output
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go: :-)

```
In [1335]: str(num)                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[1335]: '[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    x = map(lambda x: str(x), x)x = list(x)
    print(x)
    str(x)
```